# Snow/Rain fall effect on android

Tags: android, canvas

I want to achieve the snowfall effect similar to that google+ did on christmas, how should I proceed? 
Do I need to use a canvas ?

Answer (score 1):

Either use a canvas or a created animation-sequence.

Either way, overlay the view over the entire layout, and then start it.

Comment: Do I need to use some kind of particle system here, to make snow flakes? (Its mentioned a lot of times over the internet but I believe those are for games not for simple application)

Comment: You could if you want a really high-quality effect, or you can just get a couple different images of snowflakes (for diversity) and then just have their y value continuously decrease with their x value moving at some constant rate (depending on the effect you want).